SAS use proc transpose to make long race and ethnicity variables wide
I am using 10 years CDC population data to run an analysis by state and year. Within the analysis, I am going to use race and ethnicity data. The issue I am having is figuring out how to use proc transpose to make each race and ethnicity its own column while keeping the accurate population data per state and year.
The data currently look like this:
State   Year Race Eth Pop
Alabama 2010 White NH xxxx
Alabama 2010 Black NH xxxx
Alabama 2010 Asian NH xxxx
Alabama 2010 AI/AN H  xxxx


Here is an example of how the raw data look:

I would like the data to look like this:
State    Year White/NH Black/NH Asian/NH AI/AN/H
Alabama  2010  xxxx      xxxx    xxxx     xxxx

Can I do that with proc transpose? I apologize in advance if there is a better way to format the way I want the data to look I am not adept at question writing on here.
Thank you!!

What did you try?  Show the PROC TRANSPOSE code you ran. Did it not run?  Show the SAS LOG with the error messages.  Did it run but not produce what you want?  Explain in what way it is not what you want.

To share data just post it as text.  don't know to get it as text?  Just use a data null with a PUT statement.  You can include a FILE statement to specify a delimiter, like a comma. data _null_; set have; file log dsd; put state year gender race ethnicity population; run;

We'll use Race and Eth as our ID to create our variables, and transpose it by state and year. We can use a / as a delimiter by treating it as a name literal.
proc transpose data=have 
               out=want(drop=_NAME_)
               delimiter='/'n;
    by state year;
    id race eth;
    var pop;
run; 

State   Year    White/NH    Black/NH    Asian/NH    AI/AN/H
Alabama 2010    xxxx        xxxx        xxxx        xxxx


Thank you so much for replying!!! When I tried to emulate that code I got the following error: ERROR: The ID value "American_Indian_or_Alaska_Native" occurs twice in the same BY group. Is there a way around this error?

You have duplicate values somewhere in your data. You'll have to remove them or aggregate them.

For this particular dataset, If I remove those duplicate values I am losing important data. Can I use proc transpose with those duplicate values? For each year and state, the dataset goes through every possible combination. EX: AI/AN Hispanic, AI/AN non-hispanic, AI/AN blank. It will do this for each state and year

Can you post your example with the duplicate data?

I edited the original question with a screenshot of the data

You'll need to aggregate it first by state, year, and ethnicity, then transpose. PROC TRANSPOSE does not do any aggregating.

You can only get duplicates if there are multiple observations with the same values of STATE, YEAR, RACE and ETH.  Why would you have such records?  Can you look at them and see a pattern?
